# A proof concering $\Re(\log\zeta(\sigma+it))$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I have been trying to prove that
$$\Re(\log\zeta(\sigma+it))=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^\sigma\log n}\cos(t\log n),$$
but now I've given up, so I looked up the answer in the back of the [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=54y1jO6CQYEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=sv&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). It starts just the same way I was trying to go:

\begin{align*}
\log\zeta(s)&=-\sum_p\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right) \\
&=\sum_p\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{kp^{ks}}.
\end{align*}

But then the author just jumps right to the solution, not giving any intermediary step(s):

$$\sum_p\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{kp^{ks}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^\sigma\log n}\{\cos(t\log n)-i\sin(t\log n)\}.$$

Can someone please help me see what is going on in the last step?

Comment: Start by writing $p^{-ks}$ as $\exp(-ks \log p)$, where $s = \sigma + it$.

Comment: @Erick: Ok, then what?

Comment: You are familiar with Euler's formula, no?  Also, it might help to work from the right and replace the summation over $n$ with summation over prime powers $p^k$ (all other terms are $0$ thanks to the $\Lambda(n)$).